# Error: Car.Form1 is inaccessible due to its protection level C#

Tags: c#

I cant figure out 2 errors in this code can someone help me please?

error 1: Car.Form1 is inaccessible due to its protection level

error 2: The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Thanks for the help!

Main class

```
namespace Car
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 500;
    int turn = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {


            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                x += 32;
                turn = 1;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                x -= 32;
                turn = 2;
                Wheel1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                Wheel2.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
            }
            else
            {
                turn = 0;
            }
            if (x <= -250)
            {
                x = 1040;
            }
            else if (x >= 1041)
            {
                x = -250;
            }


    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

car class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Car
{
     public class Car : Form
     {
        public Car(Form1 form1)
        {
            form1.Car.Location = new Point(form1.x, form1.y);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: do you know you are adding a form to a form?

Comment: You mis-spelled the error message.  You wrote what you *thought* it said instead of what it *really* said.  It complained about Form1.Car, not Car.Form1.  Picking good identifier names is *important*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `form1.Car.Location` I believe `Car` is some control on your form. By default all controls are `private` and not visible outside of form class. Fast solution: select your `Car` control in designer, and go to its properties. Find property `Modifiers` and change it to `public`. That will generate public field for your control, but it will also break encapsulation of your form. Better create method on form for moving car to new location. Something like:

public void MoveCar(Point location)
   {
       Car.Location = location;
   }

[`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) is declared in `System.Drawing` namespace.